# Error occurring in onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net

The error in browser its showing like this
`ASP.student_aspxstudentdashboard_aspx'` does not contain a definition for `'btnBindCourseData_OnClick'`

and

> no extension method 'btnBindCourseData_OnClick' accepting a first argument of type `'ASP.student_aspxstudentdashboard_aspx'` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and help in how to use repeater.

and my code is

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBindCourseData" runat="server" Text="Bind" OnClick="btnBindCourseData_OnClick" />
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCertificateCourseName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CourseName") %>' Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfUnitInfoCourseID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("IdCourse") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>



 protected void btnBindCourseData_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        UnitBLL objUnitBll = new UnitBLL();
        List<CourseMasterDTO> lstCourseMaster = new List<CourseMasterDTO>();

        lstCourseMaster = objUnitBll.bindCourseData();

        Repeater repeater1 = (Repeater)Master.FindControl("repeater1");

    }
```

Comment: try adding like this `Repeater repeater1 = (Repeater)Master.FindControl("btnBindCourseData");`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rebuild your code once and have to check again, or remove the event from button click and regenerate it again, it happened to me, might work for you.

Comment: Rebuild is not working and on double click on button in design the event is not generating.

Comment: Just remove OnClick="btnBindCourseData_OnClick"  and then click button..i think this helps you.

Comment: then make sure that codebehind file source is okay in aspx file header code.

Comment: @PradnyaBolli that i tried but onclick is not generating

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your C# code, try by pasting the following code. C# is case-sensitive.

```
void btnBindCourseData_OnClick(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    UnitBLL objUnitBll = new UnitBLL();
    List<CourseMasterDTO> lstCourseMaster = new List<CourseMasterDTO>();
    lstCourseMaster = objUnitBll.bindCourseData();
    Repeater repeater1 = (Repeater)Master.FindControl("repeater1");
}
```